# what does "pillbox" mean in this line "way to be a pillbox"

Tags: meaning

What does **pillbox** mean in this line taken from a TV series called *Manifest*?

> -- Way to be a **pillbox**.
>
> -- Wait, where do I know that from?
>
> -- That was Evie's favorite insult.
>
> -- No, no, no.
>
> -- Her favorite insult was bitch-monkey.
>
> -- Bitch-monkey.

Comment: Where is this quote from?

Comment: from a tv series called manifest

Comment: Michaela, you're not an alcoholic.

You're allowed to have a glass of wine.

- No one's looking. - I'm looking.

Way to be a pillbox.

Comment: Gosh, you're quick. This is from last night's episode. Bitch-monkey is made up. Kids make up stuff all the time, and some things are literally limited to some school or other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the idiom, "Don't be such a pill!" or "You're such a pill!" which is used to express the idea that the person is a party-pooper or is aggravating you or getting on your nerves. The person is "hard to take".  This appears to be a "one-upping" of that idiom, calling the person an entire box of pills.